# Unable to run my remote event receiver "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, remote-event-receiver

I have an office 365 farm + visual studio 2015 professional. now i want to create a new remote event receiver, so i did the following steps:-

1. I create a new project of type "SharePoint Add-in":-

[image]

2. then i chose the type as sharepoint-hosted app:-

[image]

3. and the environment as SharePoint online:-
   [image]
4. then i added a remote event receiver:-

[image]

but i got this error:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.            0
```

as follow:-

[image]

i access the following location inside my dev machine:-

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\
```

and i find the Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools exists, as follow:-

[image]
so the question is why the VS project can not load this ? so can anyone advice what is going on ?
side note. the error which i am getting is referring to a file with version = 15.0.0.0, while i am developing add-in for office 365 so the version should be 16 instead of 15 ? is this correct? and can this reveal the problem i am facing?

Comment: Have you run `Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` from Nuget?

Comment: @TrevorSeward thanks for the reply.. now i install the package, then i close/reopen visual studio, after that i tried to add a new remote ER but i got the exact error..

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you please advice on my above comment ?

Comment: Can you try with provider hosted app ? SharePoint hosted apps don't support remote event receivers ? Also ensure that the SharePoint online url is valid

Comment: And you have .Net framework >= 4.5 rite?

Comment: @GautamSheth now all the tutorials i read about creating remote ER will start by creating sharepoint-hosted app for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQPbsEUy-wE , then they add a new item of type remote ER, which will act as the provider-hosted...

Comment: @little_big_thoughts yes i am using .net 4.5

Comment: @GautamSheth i just open visual studio 2015, then i create a new SP-addin of type provider hosted app, i enter the site url, then i chose MVC, which mainly created a new mvc web application, after that i tried to add a new remote ER to the project but i got the same error, i also try to run the new project but i got the same error...

Comment: That's strange. Can you uninstall the SP Online client components from control panel > installed programs and reinstall again and then check ? Could be that there is some dll conflict. Also, just to be sure, can you open VS 2015 in admin mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things you can look into:

1) Ensure that you are using the VS 2015 Update 3 (preferred). ( Open VS and check Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio)

2) Also, it looks like some issue(most probably) with Office Developer tools. So, you can download and install the latest using Web Platform Installer(WPI) 5.0 and search for Office tools as below:

[image]

Download link for WPI - [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Once WPI is installed, install the office tool mentioned in above pic and then restart Visual studio and then check.

Also, you can uninstall and reinstall the SPO Client components SDK and then check again.

Download for SDK - [SPO Client components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038) or download via Nuget as suggested by Trevor Seward.

Yes, the version should be `16.0.x.x`.

Also, RERs are supported only in Provider hosted app(PHA) not in SharePoint hosted app. So, you should create a PHA and add the RER to the SharePoint project.

**Update - SharePoint works in mysterious ways.**

Turns out, to do SharePoint online app development, we need to also install `SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK` as well besides `SharePoint online client components SDK`. There seems to be a dependency of online component on the 2013 SDK.

Once installed, this error will disappear.

Restart visual studio and then create a new project to test out.

Download link - [SharePoint Server 2013 Client components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. now let me start from the beginning to describe my current situation.  i have VS 2015 professional version 14.0.25 update 3. i also have  WPI installed and inside it, it mentioned that the "Microsoft Office Developer tools update 2 for VS 2015 " is already installed... so what should i do now ? shold i uninstall SPO cleint components and re-install them ?

Comment: yes that might help. Also, can you check if the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` dlls are present at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI` location ?

Comment: now inside the control panel i can not find SPO Client components SDK  .. i can only see  a program named "sharepoint client components" and not "sharepoint online client components".. for the location `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI` yes the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` is already there...

Comment: so what do u think ? now i already run this commadn `Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` inside my project but it did not fix the problem..

Comment: @Guatam now i try downloading the sdk from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038 but when i try to install the `sharepointclientcomponents_16-6906-1200_x64-en-us.msi` i got an error that another version of this product is already installed !!

Comment: hmm strange, can you check if the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and related folders are present in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` path, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlJn.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcdAJ.png)? Also, yes would recommend that you uninstall the SharePoint client components and reinstall using the download link mentioned above

Comment: so now to understand the case exactly so there are 2 programs one named `SharePoint client components` while the other named `SharePoint online client components`?? as in my case inside the control panel i only have "SharePoint client components" ?? so should i uninstall it then reinstall the SPO client component ?

Comment: No, there will be only one, `SharePoint client components`. Uninstall that and reinstall using the link i mentioned. Apologies, if i created any confusion.

Comment: ok i got your point. but keeping in mind that the version for the "Sharepoint online components" is `16.0.6518.1200` inside the control panel ,, but not sure why visual studio is trying to load the one with version 15.. anyway will re-install as suggested from ur end.. thanks. unfortunately i do not have enough reputation score to like ur value replies..

Comment: now i uninstall the "SharePoint client components" from control panel, then i download the newer version from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038 then i install sharepointclientcomponents_16-6906-1200_x64-en-us, after that i try to create a new SP-hosted add-in, but when i try to add ERE i got the exact same error as the on mentioned inside my original question, i also try creating a new provider-hosted add-in, but when i try to add RER i got the same error!! not sure why VS is trying to load the version 15, although i mentioned that i need it for SP online!!

Comment: second question, now from the error message i am receiving when trying to add a new RER, it mentioned that "it can not connect to the site url or the current user does not have permission on the site"?? now i am running VS using my account, while the SP add-in url is for our customer, so my username does not have permission to access the url... could this be the problem? if so then how i can fix it? should i login to the VS using the customer account admin username ??? i am totally lost...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71399/discussion-between-gautam-sheth-and-john-g).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if SharePoint Client SDK componment has been installed in your local PC, because remote event receiver needs SharePoint CSOM supported, you can download and install from below:

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: so which version i need to install `16-6518-1200` or
`16-6906-1200` ??

Comment: 16-6906-1200 in above link, sdk will register to GAC, it should fix this error

Comment: i got an error that another version of this product is already installed...

Comment: @Jerry_SPWX it's preferable to use the NuGet package rather than the downloadable version of the SDK.

Comment: @TrevorSeward thanks for the reply.. now i install the package from Nuget, then i close/reopen visual studio, after that i tried to add a new remote ER but i got the exact error..

Comment: @Jerry_SPWX can you please advice on my above comments please?